# Correlation Coefficient r, Formula Explained Intuitively

Tags: statistics, correlation, bivariate-distributions

I've seen several videos, Khan Academy included, explaining the correlation coefficient formula but none explain the "logic" behind the formula, not to my satisfaction anyways.

The Formula: `r = 1 / n-1 ∑(x z-score)(y z-score)` *condensed the formula a bit for the z-scores*

As I have it understood, the r coefficient **is the average of the product of the z-scores**

**Questions**

1. But why? What is the logic behind finding the average product of the z-scores?
2. What does the first part of the equation mean? `1 / n-1` the denominator looks like the sample population but why have `1` divided by the sample  population?

**Summary**

The answer(s) I'm looking for would be something like, "We need to calculate the correlation between x and y and in order to do that we need to..." In other words, in intuitive approach to explaining the why of the formula.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think an honest explanation has to have more than one English sentence with no symbols. I have tried to give an intuitive account of this in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scatterplot of 100 points, both x-values and y-values are roughly standard normal (that is, they are z-scores).

[image]

Notice in particular the first point, which is circled in *red*, roughly at
$(0.41, 0.18)$ in the upper-right quadrant.
It's contribution to the total $T = \sum_i x_iy_1$ is
$x_1y_1 = 0.41(0.18) = +0.0738.$

In upper-right quadrant, all points have $x_i > 0$ and $y_i > 0$
and so they will all make positive contributions to $T.$

Similarly, points in the lower-left quadrant will all have $x_i <  0$ and $y_i < 0$ (both coordinates negative), so they will also all make positive contributions to $T.$

By contrast, the points in the other two quadrants will
have one positive and one negative coordinate, so they will make negative contributions to the sum $T.$

In our sample, the correlation is positive. That is when $x$-values increase than corresponding $y$-values also tend to increase. Specifically, for the points in the figure
$r = +0.567.$ The total $T$ has both positive and negative contributions, but the positive contributions win out because there are many more points in the upper-right and lower-left quadrants than in the other two quadrants.

If all 100 points were on an upward-sloping diagonal
line through the origin, then all points would make
*positive* contributions towards the correlation. The
largest possible result.

One can prove mathematically that the regression coefficient $r = \frac{1}{n-1}T$ is always between
$-1$ and $+1.$ That is, $ -1 \le r \le 1.$

One reason for dividing $T$ by $n - 1$ is so that this convenient
rule will hold true. [The denominator has to depend on
$n$ because as we add more points to the plot, the total $T$ tends to become increasing large in absolute value.]

*Note:* Technically, the reason it's $n-1$ instead of $n$ is that in computing $z$-scores we divide by the the two sample standard deviations, both of which have $n-1$ in their denominators: $$r = \frac{1}{n=1}T = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i \left(\frac{X_i-\bar X}{S_x}\right) \left(\frac{Y_i -\bar Y}{S_y}\right),$$
where $S_x^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i (X_i - \bar X)^2,$ and similarly for $S_y^2.$

Comment: why are z-scores X multiplied by z-scores Y? I understand it's because you will get positive or negative correlation but if a data point lies on X or Y mean the data point coordinate on the other axis will be useless/lost (the data point will count only as a whole as a little lost in correlation) because the multiplication will give 0. Is this loss of information the best we can do? What am i missing?